# When does Google Play Games services reset weekly leaderboards?

Tags: google-play-services

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards) states that *...weekly leaderboards reset at Saturday midnight PST.* Is this the night from Friday to Saturday or from Saturday to Sunday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's documentation now clearly states this in [Leaderboard Time Frames](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#leaderboard_time_frames) as

> Weekly leaderboards reset at midnight between Saturday and Sunday, in the same timezone as daily leaderboards (UTC-7).

As per above documentation, a new week starts on `Sunday 00:01 AM PDT/UTC-7` for GPGS leaderboards.

Answer (score 2):

Midnight is 00:00. This only occurs on a Saturday once a week, and that is right after Friday 23:59.

Comment: Just to be clear: Saturday midnight does NOT follow Saturday evening but preceeds it?